# How is *y++ = *z++ evaluated?

Tags: c, pointers, operators, expression, increment

I'm a bit confused because of this code here..

```
 int main()
{
 int x=30, *y, *z;
 y=&x; /* Assume address of x is 500 and integer is 4 byte size */
 z=y;
 *y++=*z++;
 x++;
 printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d\n", x, y, z);
 return 0;
 }
```

I don't understand `*y++=*z++;`

I know that here it will be like===>*(504)=*(504);
but i don't know what will happen after that with assign operator and *.

Comment: How does `*y = *z` make sense to begin with? It's the same thing as writing `x=x`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
*y++ = *z++;
```

is basically equivalent to

```
int *old_y = y;
y = y + 1;

int *old_z = z;
z = z + 1;

*old_y = *old_z;
```

It takes the values where `y` is currently pointing, and assign it to where `z` is currently pointing. Then it increases both `y` and `z` so they point somewhere else.

And considering that `y` and `z` are both pointing to `x`, it's essentially the same as:

```
x = x;
```

---

On a related note, to print a pointer with `printf` you need to use the `%p` format (and cast the pointer to `void *`). Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I think `y = y + 1;` invokes UB as `y` points to a local `int` and not an array.

Comment: @AlexLop. You may point 1 item beyond the pointed-at item, but you may not de-reference such a pointer.

Comment: @AlexLop. Not really, modifying the pointer itself doesn't lead to UB. But attempting to dereference the pointer *after* `y++` will lead to UB.

Comment: I am not 100% sure about that. The standard says that you are allowed to point to one element beyond the array limit.  So pointing two elements beyond the limit is UB, right? Now in this case, I am not sure `int x;` is the same as `int x[1]` from the C standard point of view.

Comment: @AlexLop.: The C standard explicitly says that, for purposes of pointer arithmetic, a single object like `int x` is treated like an array of one element. And the increments shown in the code advance the pointer to one element beyond the array, not two.

Comment: @AlexLop. Technically you can assign a pointer object by any arbitrary value it can hold. That is not UB. UB is to actually attempt to access this memory location and refer to it as a valid object by dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: The C standard does not define the behavior when pointers are assigned arbitrary values. Rules for this involve the conversion rules in 6.3.2.3 and the pointer arithmetic rules in 6.5.6. In essence, an underlying problem is that not all C implementations use flat address spaces. Their pointers may be compound data structures, involving segments, offsets, and even data structures in memory. Using the value of a pointer, not the object it points to, may itself require accessing data structures in memory, and that can fail with invalid pointer values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What I tried to pointing at is only the assignment itself. As a pointer is an object in memory, an assignment by a value in the range of values it can represent should not cause any undefined behavior per se. - I should have add "For example, UB is ...".

Answer (score 1):

```
*y++ = *z++;
```

The `*` operator is to dereference a pointer. Means you access the object pointed to by the pointer.

The `++` operator is to increment an operand by `1`. In this case, you actually increment the pointers itself, but not the object(s) pointed to. When and where the pointers exactly get incremented is compiler-dependent, but it is guaranteed that the incrementation took place after the statement.

Nonetheless, It is guaranteed that the value of the pointers before the incrementation is used inside of the expression.

So, with this statement, the object pointed to by `y` will get the value of the object pointed to by `z`.  As both `y` and `z` point to `x`, the statement is equivalent to `x = x;` and therefore pretty useless.

After the statement, the (address) values of the pointers `y` and `z` are incremented by `sizeof(int)` Bytes.

---

Also:

```
printf("x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z);
```

is wrong. You don´t dereference `y` and `z` to access `x`. In this way actually attempt to print the values of the pointers itself, which is furthermore invalid because you use the wrong format specifier `%d` instead of `%p` (with a pointer cast to type `void*` as argument to be standard-compliant) to do that. Thus, the behavior is undefined.

It should be

```
printf("x = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", x, *y, *z);
```

Note that since `y` and `z` are incremented, dereferencing the pointers in this case will also invoke undefined behavior, because they actually point to no valid object anymore.

The incrementations of `y` and `z` would be useful if they would f.e. point to an array.

---

As an example, this will help you to more understand what is actually going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x[2] = {30, 50};
    int *y, *z;

    y = x;
    z = y;
    *y++ = *z++;

    x[0]++;

    printf("x[0] = %d, x[1] = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", x[0], x[1], *y, *z);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x[0] = 31, x[1] = 50, y = 50, z = 50
```

Comment: Re “it increments the operand after the statement - Means the incrementation does not have an effect inside of the statement, but thereafter”: This is wrong and is the subject of **numerous** Stack Overflow questions. The increment must happen before the sequence point that ends the statement but may happen anywhere within statement execution not otherwise controlled by sequencing rules. The fact that the value of the operand from before the increment is the value used in the expression does not mean the actual increment does not occur before the value is used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It could increment the operand but uses the value of the operand before the incrementation? That´s tricky. But is it a constraint that the value from before the incrementation have to be used in the expression or is this undefined/ implementation-defined?

Comment: The problem is not that the value from before the increment is used as the value in this particular part of the expression but that, if the statement uses the same object elsewhere, there is no sequencing between the increment required here and the value used there. The increment could happen before, after, or **during** the other use of the value. That is why the C standard made `x + x++` undefined. If `x` is some 128-bit integer that the compiler implements using instructions for 32-bit integers, it needs multiple instructions for the increment…

Comment: … If the instructions that read `x` get interleaved with the instructions to increment `x`, then the value loaded is neither the value before the increment nor after but is a mishmash. Of course, a compiler can be designed not to do that with `x + x++`, but, with `*p + *q++`, it generally cannot know at compile time that `p` and `q` point to the same object. Having to support that would impede optimization, so the C standard makes it undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I understand what you mean, but isn´t that different here because `x` isn´t incremented? It is used as value to be assigned (`*z++`) and also as object to get assigned (`*p++`). But there is no incrementation of `x` itself. Rather the pointers get incremented. - 1. `z` get incremented, but `x` is used regardless of the incrementation of `z`. - 2. `x` is assigned to the object, `y` has pointed to before the incrementation of itself, actually `x`. The result is `x = x;`. That should be fine or am I wrong?

Comment: The behavior in this code is not undefined, but telling people that the increment happens after the statement is incorrect and causes them to reason incorrectly about other statements that involve increments. This issue is one of the problems that comes up on Stack Overflow most frequently and disseminating correct information about it is important.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I corrected this statement. Thank you for the hint.